# How to generate random x and y coordinates using box muller transformation

Tags: python, random, range, coordinates, standard-deviation

I'm attempting to generate random `x` and `y` integer values within a certain range (roughly -10 to +10) using a box muller transformation.

I've logged a dataset and calculated my standard deviations for each axis as `sdX = 4.413680773` and `sdY = 4.361846901`.

I've tried to read up about box muller transformations, however I haven't been able to find much clear information that doesn't involve greek characters as I haven't done that kind of math in several years. If anybody could explain in simple english how i'd approach this, or even with python code examples that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems more like a math-ish question than coding imo.... have you considered math.stackexchange or similar?

Comment: No, as I was looking for code that easily explains the math, not just an explanation for the math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to implement the box-muller transformation yourself. If you want to generate a normal distribution of random numbers, you can use numpy directly.

```
import numpy as np
mu_x, sigma_x = 0, 4.413680773
s = np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, 1000)
```

If you want generate some random from 2 dimensions gaussian distribution, you have to calculate the Covariance and use np.random.multivariate_normal

```
mean = (1, 2)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
points = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards the random normal function. I believe it will prove to be exactly what I need after playing around with it a bit. For a 2 dimensional array, I assume that generating an x value using what you've provided followed by a y variable using its own standard deviation would be a simple and effective route to take

Answer (score 1):

The amount of code needed to generate normal RVs via Box-Muller is not much. Most of the code below sets up visualizations so we can convince ourselves the method is correct.

It's not clear what you mean by a rough (-10, 10) range. I am generating standard normal variables in this code. You may scale or shift them as needed.

**Code:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy

# generate two sets of U(0, 1) random variables
u1 = np.random.uniform(size=10000)
u2 = np.random.uniform(size=10000)

# generate *independent* normal random variables using Box-Muller
R_sq = -2 * np.log(u1)
theta = 2 * np.pi * u2
z1 = np.sqrt(R_sq) * np.cos(theta)
z2 = np.sqrt(R_sq) * np.sin(theta)

# compute theoretical normal distribution
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 1000)
y = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)

# plot (kernel density estimated) empirical distribution against theoretical
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
axes[0].plot(x, y, label='empirical')
sns.kdeplot(z1, ax=axes[0], label='theoretical')
axes[1].plot(x, y, label='empirical')
sns.kdeplot(z2, ax=axes[1], label='theoretical')
plt.show()

# print correlation matrix of z1 and z2 (as evidence of their independence)
print(np.corrcoef(z1, z2))
```

**Console Output:**
Here, we see exactly 1 on the main diagonal (indicating perfect correlation between z1 and z1 and between z2 and z2), and nearly 0 correlation between z1 and z2. (Zero correlation does not imply independence. However, if z1 and z2 are independent, they will have zero correlation. This is just a litmus test.)

```
[[ 1.         -0.00842543]
 [-0.00842543  1.        ]]
```

**Visualization:**
To convince ourselves we actually generated normal RVs.

[image]