What kind of plot is this called? And how do I plot it with matplotlib?
I came across this paper which presented this plot below. Could someone share what is this kind of plot called? And how can I plot a similar chart with python, specifically matplotlib? I would need to present predictions from a log regression as well, hence the question.
Thanks!


looks like a boxplot or an errorbar

If the input are many individual measurements, you could create something similar with seaborn. sns.pointplot(data=..., x=..., y=..., hue=..., linestyle='none')where data points to a dataframe, x and y to the columns used for the x and y-axis, hue to the column that groups into different colors.

Note that to be suitable for StackOverflow, your post should include some reproducible test data, and your best-effort code. A regression line would need a numeric x-axis, making your question a bit confusing.

At First Glance...
This is almost certainly an error bar with grouped partitions. Since you asked how one can plot such a graph, let's understand some basics first.

Error Bars Primer
Definition
An error bar is a graph used to model and/or illustrate variability and uncertainty as an heuristic of data analysis. It allows you to visualize the precision of data points, and it can be used to model standard deviation, standard error, confidence intervals, or range (Cumming, Fidler & Vaux, 2007). This is done through the use of markers drawn over the original graph and its data points, juxtaposed with cap-tipped lines (or caps) extending from the center of the plotted data point.
Caps add a touch of visual aesthetics to your plot (subjective opinion), helping you quickly conceptualize the boundaries in relation to your data points. The sample you've provided however (if it is indeed an error bar), does not utilize caps. This can actually enhance visibility of the error bar endpoints which might be useful in plots with many overlapping elements.
A relatively short error bar signifies a condensed/concentrated value distribution, meaning that the data implied average is more likely. Contrastingly, a relatively long error bar is the obvious antithesis - it suggests sparse/wide distribution and that the average value is less unlikely.
Anatomy of an Error Bar (source)

Furthermore, Error bars can be symmetrical (the same length above and below the data point) or asymmetrical (varying lengths).
Error bars can be applied to scatterplots, dot plots, bar charts, or line graphs, to provide an additional layer of details that expands on the information presented by the initial data (The Data Visualization Catalogue article).
The error value in such a graph is the amounts by which your data points deviates from the expected value, and can be specified as fixed value or as a percentage of the data point (the latter, I believe is what your source image has presented).
Interpretation
In regards to your source material which I've also studied briefly, my interpretation (of the particular cropped portion in your question) is the authors seem to be testing a probabilistic model analyzing the likelihood of vaccinated patients to be hospitalized upon experiencing severe Omicron variant infections, against actual outcomes recorded in reality. So the error bars is used there as a measure of the distribution of accuracy of the model's results. In the ML sense, I believe it's a way of asking:

How well does the model fit the training data?


Error Bars in Matplotlib
A Simple Error Bar
The official documentation has a rich collection of useful error bar examples, but let's buildup from basics all the way to plotting an identical one to your sample.
You can draw a simple error bar using matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar() as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [10, 20, 30]
yerr = [2, 3, 1]  # Error values for y

# Create a plot with error bars
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt="o", capsize=5, label="Data with error bars")

# Label axes
plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")

# Show legend
plt.legend()

# Show plot
plt.show()


Output:

The key takeaway is the fact that we have our error values readily available and easily pass it to the yerr parameter of errorbar(), everything else is pretty much trivial.
To achieve a capless error bar plot, you can always set the capsize parameter of errorbar() to 0. Similarly, you can also plot your error bar data points with markers by specifying an additional keyword argument marker to errorbar() with any of the following values: 'o', 's', '^', 'D', 'P'. We'll be doing this in a more sophisticated way when we attempt to plot an identical graph to your sample.
So, "How can I plot a similar chart in Python with Matplotlib?"
The code for generating the plot in your sample would look something like this. It is quite straightforward and self-explanatory, but since I'm making up (almost a close guesstimation to the actual data points but ultimately bogus) data points, I've strategically spaced out the intervals for the data points.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Categories/x-axis data and their positions
categories = ["Primary + booster < 1yr", "Primary + booster >= 1yr", "At most primary"]
positions = np.arange(len(categories))

# Set the y-axis label and ticks
ax.set_ylabel("Probability hospital (%)")
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 25))

# Set the x-axis with categorical labels
ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(categories)

# Define the colors and markers
colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
markers = ['o', 's', '^', 'D', 'P']

# Define the offsets for spacing the error bars
offsets = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, len(colors))

# Guesstimations of vertical lines with different ranges for each category
y_ranges = [
    [(45, 50), (50, 55), (52, 58), (48, 53), (47, 56)],
    [(55, 60), (60, 65), (62, 68), (58, 63), (57, 66)],
    [(75, 80), (80, 85), (82, 88), (78, 83), (77, 86)]
]

# Plot the error bars for each category
for i, ranges in enumerate(y_ranges):
    for j, (color, marker, offset, (ymin, ymax)) in enumerate(zip(colors, markers, offsets, ranges)):
        x_position = positions[i] + offset  # Adjust x position with offset
        y = (ymin + ymax) / 2  # Center point for marker
        yerr = (ymax - ymin) / 2  # Error value for the error bar      # capsize=5
        ax.errorbar(x_position, y, yerr=yerr, fmt=marker, color=color, capsize=0, label=f'{categories[i]} - Line {j+1}')

# Add internal text-label in the top-left corner
ax.text(0.05, 0.95, "At least 60 yrs", transform=ax.transAxes,
        fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='none'))

# Bborder to the plot
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('black')

# Show the plot
plt.show()


Output:


Last Considerations: What if it's not an Error Bar (however unlikely)?
Provided you have your data points, you can still manually plot something identical using ordinary line graph functionalities of Matplotlib.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Categories/x-axis data and their positions
categories = ["Primary + booster < 1yr", "Primary + booster >= 1yr", "At most primary"]
positions = np.arange(len(categories))

# Set the y-axis label and ticks
ax.set_ylabel("Probability hospital (%)")
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 25))

# Set the x-axis with categorical labels
ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(categories)

# Colors and markers
colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
markers = ['o', 's', '^', 'D', 'P']

# Offsets for spacing the vertical lines
offsets = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, len(colors))

# Guesstimations of vertical lines with different ranges for each category
range_limits = [(45, 60), (55, 70), (75, 90)]
y_ranges = [
    [(45, 50), (50, 55), (52, 58), (48, 53), (47, 56)],
    [(55, 60), (60, 65), (62, 68), (58, 63), (57, 66)],
    [(75, 80), (80, 85), (82, 88), (78, 83), (77, 86)]
]

for i, (limits, ranges) in enumerate(zip(range_limits, y_ranges)):
    for j, (color, marker, offset, (ymin, ymax)) in enumerate(zip(colors, markers, offsets, ranges)):
        x_position = positions[i] + offset  # Adjust x position with offset
        y = (ymin + ymax) / 2  # Center point for marker
        ax.vlines(x_position, ymin, ymax, color=color, label=f'{categories[i]} - Line {j+1}')
        ax.scatter(x_position, y, color=color, marker=marker)

# internal text-label in the top-left corner
ax.text(0.05, 0.95, "At least 60 yrs", transform=ax.transAxes,
        fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='none'))

# Border to the plot
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('black')

# Voila!
plt.show()


Output:


Seaborn is built on Matplotlib so,
I took inspiration from JohanC's comment to use Seaborn's sns.pointplot() because it handles statistics about data that are many individual samples largely "out-of-the-box"....
This also builds largely on M.A.'s excellent answer for the data and many of the customizations beyond the largely default Seaborn result. The data here is expanded beyond that making 1000 samples per the fifteen data points in the final plot with the 15000 sample data points structured in a Pandas dataframe.
Using Seaborn: Plotting a dataframe using sns.pointplot()
This may look like a lot of code but the plot is just the last call. Most of this block is just making the data. Seaborn gives nice plots in conjunction with Pandas.
# JohanC's suggestiom for https://stackoverflow.com/q/78543170/8508004
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# to generate mock data use guesstimations from M.A.
y_ranges = [
    [(45, 50), (50, 55), (52, 58), (48, 53), (47, 56)],
    [(55, 60), (60, 65), (62, 68), (58, 63), (57, 66)],
    [(75, 80), (80, 85), (82, 88), (78, 83), (77, 86)]
]
# generate mock data
sig_factor_multiplier = 8
avgs_less_than1year = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[0]]
avgs_greater_than1year = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[1]] 
avgs_at_most_primary = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[2]]
err_range_less_than1year = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[0]]
err_range__greater_than1year = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[1]] 
err_range__at_most_primary = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[2]]
hospitals = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
def make_values_with_mean_covering_range(mu_x, sigma_x, number_values):
    return np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, number_values) # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335302/8508004


# Generate dataframe with mock data values and category labels
# first, make a list of lists with each sample probability for each hospital for under year, over, at most primary
list_o_data = []
groupdata_and_labels = [(avgs_less_than1year,err_range_less_than1year,"Primary +\nbooster < 1 yr"),(avgs_greater_than1year,err_range__greater_than1year,"Primary +\nbooster >= 1 yr"),(avgs_at_most_primary,err_range__at_most_primary,"At most\nprimary")]
for grp_ind,gdnl in enumerate(groupdata_and_labels):
    for hosp_indx,hospital in enumerate(hospitals):
        the_group_label = gdnl[2]
        the_prob_values = make_values_with_mean_covering_range(gdnl[0][hosp_indx], gdnl[1][hosp_indx], 1000)
        for pv in the_prob_values:
            list_o_data.append([hospital,the_group_label,pv])
df_labels = ['hospital', 'Groups','Probability hospital (%)']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_o_data, columns=df_labels)
## ALL THAT ABOVE WAS ONLY TO MAKE DATAFRAME ##-------------------------------------------------## ALL THAT ABOVE WAS ONLY TO MAKE DATAFRAME ##


#With the dataframe in hand, Seaborn will happily make the plot
import seaborn as sns
p = sns.pointplot(
    data=df, x="Groups", y="Probability hospital (%)",
    capsize=0, legend=False, linewidth = 1.78, 
    linestyle="none", hue="hospital",  dodge=.34 ,markers=["o", "s","^","D","P"], #marker styles based on https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/properties.html
); # this based on examples in https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html


That's a good start considering we made a dataframe and then just called sns.pointplot() with it.
One thing that is clearly an issue is that we don't want 'Groups' below the Y-axis. So we'll customize it further below.
Using Seaborn: Customizing beyond what Seaborn gives with just sns.pointplot()
That above is default from Seaborn using the dataframe and specifying some settings when calling the sns.pointplot.
We can customize further to make it look more like the example M.A made, but using original colors.
# JohanC's suggestiom for https://stackoverflow.com/q/78543170/8508004
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; NOT NEEDED ONCE I ADDED LINE BREAKS IN COLUMN LABEL, see below

# to generate mock data use guesstimations from M.A.
y_ranges = [
    [(45, 50), (50, 55), (52, 58), (48, 53), (47, 56)],
    [(55, 60), (60, 65), (62, 68), (58, 63), (57, 66)],
    [(75, 80), (80, 85), (82, 88), (78, 83), (77, 86)]
]
# generate mock data
sig_factor_multiplier = 8
avgs_less_than1year = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[0]]
avgs_greater_than1year = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[1]] 
avgs_at_most_primary = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[2]]
err_range_less_than1year = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[0]]
err_range__greater_than1year = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[1]] 
err_range__at_most_primary = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[2]]
hospitals = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
def make_values_with_mean_covering_range(mu_x, sigma_x, number_values):
    return np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, number_values) # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335302/8508004


# Generate dataframe with mock data values and category labels
# first, make a list of lists with each sample probability for each hospital for under year, over, at most primary
list_o_data = []
groupdata_and_labels = [(avgs_less_than1year,err_range_less_than1year,"Primary +\nbooster < 1 yr"),(avgs_greater_than1year,err_range__greater_than1year,"Primary +\nbooster >= 1 yr"),(avgs_at_most_primary,err_range__at_most_primary,"At most\nprimary")]
for grp_ind,gdnl in enumerate(groupdata_and_labels):
    for hosp_indx,hospital in enumerate(hospitals):
        the_group_label = gdnl[2]
        the_prob_values = make_values_with_mean_covering_range(gdnl[0][hosp_indx], gdnl[1][hosp_indx], 1000)
        for pv in the_prob_values:
            list_o_data.append([hospital,the_group_label,pv])
df_labels = ['hospital', 'Groups','Probability hospital (%)']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_o_data, columns=df_labels)
## ALL THAT ABOVE WAS ONLY TO MAKE DATAFRAME ##-------------------------------------------------## ALL THAT ABOVE WAS ONLY TO MAKE DATAFRAME ##

#plt.figure(figsize=(7.6, 6)) # similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671064/8508004 for setting plot size ; NOT NEEDED ONCE I ADDED LINE BREAKS IN COLUMN LABEL

#With the dataframe in hand, Seaborn will happily make the plot
import seaborn as sns
my_palette = {
    'a': 'black',
    'b': 'tab:blue',
    'c': 'tab:cyan',
    'd': 'gold',
    'e': 'tab:red',
}
p = sns.pointplot(
    data=df, x="Groups", y="Probability hospital (%)",
    capsize=0, legend=False, linewidth = 1.78, palette = my_palette,
    linestyle="none", hue="hospital",  dodge=.34 ,markers=["o", "s","^","D","P"], #marker styles based on https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/properties.html
) # this based on examples in https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html

# Customize the plot some
# Set the y-axis label and ticks
#a.set_ylabel("Probability hospital (%)") # works but made it unnecessary by putting label in dataframe column name
p.set_xlabel(None) # remove the 'Groups' label below categories
p.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 25))
p.set_ylim(40, 91)

# internal text-label in the top-left corner
p.text(0.03, 0.95, "At least 60 yrs", transform=p.transAxes,
        fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='none'));


Using Seaborn: Putting it all together for something like the OP provided
And more like the provided original by fixing the axis range and the markers:
# JohanC's suggestiom for https://stackoverflow.com/q/78543170/8508004
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; NOT NEEDED ONCE I ADDED LINE BREAKS IN COLUMN LABEL, see below

# to generate mock data use guesstimations from M.A.
y_ranges = [
    [(45, 50), (50, 55), (52, 58), (48, 53), (47, 56)],
    [(55, 60), (60, 65), (62, 68), (58, 63), (57, 66)],
    [(75, 80), (80, 85), (82, 88), (78, 83), (77, 86)]
]
# generate mock data
sig_factor_multiplier = 8
avgs_less_than1year = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[0]]
avgs_greater_than1year = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[1]] 
avgs_at_most_primary = [np.mean(x) for x in y_ranges[2]]
err_range_less_than1year = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[0]]
err_range__greater_than1year = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[1]] 
err_range__at_most_primary = [(x[1]-x[0])*sig_factor_multiplier for x in y_ranges[2]]
hospitals = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
def make_values_with_mean_covering_range(mu_x, sigma_x, number_values):
    return np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, number_values) # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335302/8508004


# Generate dataframe with mock data values and category labels
# first, make a list of lists with each sample probability for each hospital for under year, over, at most primary
list_o_data = []
groupdata_and_labels = [(avgs_less_than1year,err_range_less_than1year,"Primary +\nbooster < 1 yr"),(avgs_greater_than1year,err_range__greater_than1year,"Primary +\nbooster >= 1 yr"),(avgs_at_most_primary,err_range__at_most_primary,"At most\nprimary")]
for grp_ind,gdnl in enumerate(groupdata_and_labels):
    for hosp_indx,hospital in enumerate(hospitals):
        the_group_label = gdnl[2]
        the_prob_values = make_values_with_mean_covering_range(gdnl[0][hosp_indx], gdnl[1][hosp_indx], 1000)
        for pv in the_prob_values:
            list_o_data.append([hospital,the_group_label,pv])
df_labels = ['hospital', 'Groups','Probability hospital (%)']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_o_data, columns=df_labels)
## ALL THAT ABOVE WAS ONLY TO MAKE DATAFRAME ##-------------------------------------------------## ALL THAT ABOVE WAS ONLY TO MAKE DATAFRAME ##

#plt.figure(figsize=(7.6, 6)) # similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671064/8508004 for setting plot size ; NOT NEEDED ONCE I ADDED LINE BREAKS IN COLUMN LABEL

#With the dataframe in hand, Seaborn will happily make the plot
import seaborn as sns
my_palette = {
    'a': 'black',
    'b': 'tab:blue',
    'c': 'tab:cyan',
    'd': 'gold',
    'e': 'tab:red',
} #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/68616910/8508004 and https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html saying "a dictionary mapping hue levels to matplotlib colors."
p = sns.pointplot(
    data=df, x="Groups", y="Probability hospital (%)",
    capsize=0, legend=False, linewidth = 1.78, palette = my_palette,
    linestyle="none", hue="hospital",  dodge=.27 ,markers=["o", "s","D", "^","v",], markersize = 5.0, #marker styles based on https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/properties.html
) # this based on examples in https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html

# Customize the plot some
# Set the y-axis label and ticks
#a.set_ylabel("Probability hospital (%)") # works but made it unnecessary by putting label in dataframe column name
p.set_xlabel(None) # remove the 'Groups' label below categories
p.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 25))
#p.set_ylim(40, 91)

# internal text-label in the top-left corner
p.text(0.03, 0.95, "At least 60 yrs", transform=p.transAxes,
        fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='none'));



Try the code out without installing anything or logging in using a session served by the MyBinder service:
Go here and click on a 'launch binder' badge. (You can choose the specfic Jupyter flavor at the bottom.) Or just click here to launch a session. Once the session comes up, you can paste any of these blocks of code in a cell and run it and you'll get results like posted.
